# Ingress rewrite to another Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have two services running in kubernetes with url say `https://service1.abc.cloud.com` and `https://service2.abc.cloud.com`. I have routes defined in Ingress of both the services, for example my swagger path is `https://service1.abc.cloud.com/docs` and in ingress I have defined /docs to go to my service at SSO port 8082. Once SSO is successfull SSO redirects to my service1/docs route.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "service1.fullname" . }}
  labels:
{{ include "service1.labels" . | indent 4 }}
{{ include "chart.labels" . | indent 4 }}
  annotations:
{{ include "service1.annotations" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{ template "service1.dns" . }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /docs
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ template "service1.fullname" . }}
              servicePort: 8082
```

Similar ingress file is for service2.

Till now the story was all good, but there is requirement popped up that we need to have a common url for all the services and the path param for the common url will have the service name. So we have 2 ingress file for service1 and service2 now.

The new url for service1 and service2 will be:-

```
https://mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service1
https://mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service2
```

I created a common ingress file for mynamespace host as below. So now, I have 3 ingress file one for mynamespace , one for service1 and one for service2.
I know it should be one ingress file doing all the routes mapping but untill we deprecate the service1 and service2 urls we need to support the older service1 and service2 urls. Once we deprecate, we will be merging all code in one deployment and ingress.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "mynamespace.fullname" . }}
  labels:
{{ include "mynamespace.labels" . | indent 4 }}
{{ include "chart.labels" . | indent 4 }}
  annotations:
{{ include "mynamespace.ingress.annotations" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{ template "iot.dns" . }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /mynamespace/docs
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ template "service1.fullname" . }}
              servicePort: 8082
```

Problem is I'm not able to route /mynamespace/docs of mynamespace host to /docs of service1 host. I also have SSO sidecar which is at port 8082 and my service1 and service2 is at port 8080.

End goal to be achieved:- When user hits url `https://mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service1/docs` it should internally open the service1 swagger file which is hosted at `https://service1.abc.barco.cloud.com/docs`. The url in browser should not change so redirect should happen at kubernetes level and url should not change in browser.
Since i need to support old urls too, they should also work i.e. `https://service1.abc.cloud.com` and `https://service2.abc.cloud.com`

Old design below:-
[image]

New design below:-
[image]

Comment: Can you draw some diagram to show which url goes to which service? Include both old-maintained-for-backward-compatibility and new-as-per-requirement ones. Also, if there are multiple namespaces involved, do include them.

Comment: @Lukman Added the diagram for old and new design

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you issue... but why you can't create a new ingress with new host and redirect the requests for the directly for the service instead trying to redirect it to another ingress? You can keep both ingress with both hosts redirecting for the same service.

Comment: My original route is /docs so every request should go to /docs in service1 through SSO.

Answer (score 3):

I am putting my best guess here:

> You are trying to route `mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service1/docs` to `service1:8082/docs`. You are having difficulty to convert the external path `/service1/docs` to the internal path `/docs` of service1

If that is the case, what your ingress needs is the `rewrite-target` and `use-regex` annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /docs/$2
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

And the path definition needs to be suffixed with `(/|$)(.*)`:

```
- path: /service1/docs(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: Should I do this in mynamespace ingress yaml? If so, then it might require rewrite of url to service1 url.

Comment: @iAviator How many ingresses do you have? You are still not showing your full situation in your question. I was expecting a diagram that shows two incoming URLs (the old and new one) and how they should be routed to the internal path inside the pod service since you mentioned you still want the old url working. Also, from ingress to service, the url is no longer relevant, it's just the path that matters.

Comment: My approach is with 2 ingress files one with new url and one with old. I thought the question heading displays that. Rest, I can do it in a single ingress file that is the one with service1 file having 2 hosts and I will try your approach with that. This how my annotaions looks like```external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: service1.abcd.cloud.com, "mynamespace.abc.cloud.com"
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /docs/$2
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"```

Comment: Then, you need two paths: (1) `/service1/docs(/|$)(.*)` for host `mynamespace.abc.cloud.com` and (2) `/docs(/|$)(.*)` for host `service1.abc.cloud.com`. Both rewrite-target to `/docs/$2`. You comment is confusing though when you said 2 ingress files and in the next sentence you wrote "a single ingress file" ... Are you talking about the 2 ingresses routing to another single ingress? If so then that's a wrong way of using ingress. Ingress should not and cannot route to another ingress. Ingress routes to service and that's it.

Comment: Appologies for confusion.My comment meant that I have one ingress yaml for mynamespace and one for service1.I will try what you suggested

Comment: /docs(/|$)(.*) this works for service1.abc.cloud.com. But this /service1/docs(/|$)(.*) for mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service1/docs rewrites to mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service1/docs in browser. Ideally the url for this should not have changed in browser and it would have redirected internally to my service1 pod i.e. the path in ingress

 ```- path: /service1/docs(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName:service1
              servicePort: 8082```
Does that make the situation clear?

Comment: In your question you wrote "when user hits url `https://mynamespace.abc.cloud.com/service1/docs`" , meaning the browser is already pointing there. There is no url change from user point of view 
 Internally, it would be routing to `/docs` of service1 so it serves it purpose. Again, what do you actually want? Your question and comments are still confusing.

Comment: I know the root cause of it.It seems like my SSO is redirecting it to the wrong path.that is why the url change in browser.I will do this changes in SSO redirection soon and let you know.

Comment: Try configuring `frontendUrl` as suggested by https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_hostname

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite for one host only and the other not? So whats happening is for mynamespace url sso is redirecting to ```{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /docs/redirect_uri?state=ec37e243c3a2fef4917e26ce1a2a8593&session_state=3e10f114-97ea-4327-ae3a-cbe941d78bc4&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..FWUoq-weqoppPNIoeo3dRQ.Wh9bE_8as4NgxHhfMDEsfAZTETq8iahKgzmS5d-EmvzsObAySxoEsLncpXwun4gEtvEsGzdNoHXMLEP9q-NU6HKzyw5BsxkTDkgeBywanko504n2ZNk41B8hrw_-jJV1drhlWLZGg9IgF_tGWOrIw0ZIP_cjEh0"}``` And my redirect uri in sso is ```https://mynamspace.abc.cloud.com/*```

Comment: Use separate ingresses

Comment: Ok, so now i have resolved my issue for sso too. So its all working for me now. Thanks @Lukman